# Deploying on heroku from a PhpStorm project

Tags: php, css, heroku, deployment, phpstorm

I have a php project made in PhpStorm, is there a way to deploy it directly to a heroku app?

I tried to push the PhpStorm project on a GitHub repository and connected the repository to my heroku app. I was able to change the PDO coding to make it work with an heroku psql addon, but I still have trouble in:

- having the CSS stylesheet rendered;
- having PHP sessions work;
- having JavaScripts work.

I am new to deploying and I can't really manage to understand what I have to do.

Is there someone who was able to deploy a PhpStorm project on a heroku app? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need to be specific with the *troubles* you are facing. We need more details to understand what went wrong, along with any errors you get. I use both phpstorm and heroku just the way you mentioned and don't face any of the mentioned issues. For starters, provide us with your folder structure and how you link to your css/js files

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. 
Here's my project: github.com/RiccardoSpolaor/Game_Store 
My css is in web/css and I have a javascripts script in config/configurations.php
I am not sure how I can link to them. I tried with a Procfile to link to the css file, but it didn't work.

Comment: We'll need you to post the relevant piece of code and details in your question for future references. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Try creating a test webpage & see what exactly doesn't work. If you're getting css rendering issues - create a test page(s) & try to adjust & re-deploy it & observe what exactly doesn't work

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll try what you said.